# Find polygons to the left and right from the line

Tags: postgresql, postgis

I have table of lines, and table of polygons. Some lines (maybe 1% of all lines) are on boundaries between polygons (most of lines just lay inside one polygon).

How to effectively determine polygon "on the left" and "on the right" of given line?

This is my current experiment: make parallel lines 1 meter to the left and right (ST_OffsetCurve), take first geometry in result, since it is possibly multilinestring (ST_GeometryN), take middle point of these lines (ST_LineInterpolatePoint), and query polygons containing these points (ST_Contains).

```
... WHERE ST_Contains(polygon.geom, ST_Transform(ST_LineInterpolatePoint(ST_GeometryN(ST_OffsetCurve(ST_Transform(line.geom,3857), -1),1), 0.5), 4326)
```

It works, but it is very slow (of course, there are GIST indexes on geometries).

Any idea how to speed it up, or maybe different approach altogether to determine polygons on the left and right?

Comment: Can you show the complete query and `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)` output for the query? You may miss some polygons by taking the middle point. Isn't "left" and "right" pretty arbitrary unless the line has a direction?

Answer (score 0):

If your tables are `polygons` and `lines`, I'd suggest filtering in the **join** with `ST_Intersects`:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM polygones p INNER JOIN lines l ON ST_Intersects(p.geom, l.geom)
WHERE 
ST_Contains(
    polygon.geom, 
    ST_Transform(
        ST_LineInterpolatePoint(
            ST_GeometryN(
                ST_OffsetCurve(
                    ST_Transform(line.geom,3857)
                    , -1)
                , 1)
            , 0.5)
        , 4326)
    )
```